# SQLite id field - autofill

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I've added a new table to my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
myId ID NOT NULL,
aNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
anUniqueTextId TEXT NOT NULL,
aText TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY(myId, anUniqueTextId) ON CONFLICT IGNORE,
FOREIGN KEY(anUniqueTextId, aNumber) REFERENCES otherTable(otherTableId, otherTableValue2) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now I want to insert values without manually finding out which index should I put in `myId` field:

```
[myDatabase inTransaction:^(FMDatabase *db, BOOL *rollback) {
        [db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(?,?,?)",
//         @(myData.myId), //I don't want to insert it manually
         @(aNumber),
         myData.anUniqueTextId,
         myData.aText];

        if (db.lastErrorCode) {
            NSLog(@"Huston, we've got a problem: %@", db.lastError.localizedDescription);
        }
}];
```

Ofc, I get here an error telling:

```
table myTable has 4 columns but 3 values were supplied
```

Now the question is how to insert the data to make this field autoinsert myId? I'm not sure if my insert code is invalid or CREATE TABLE statement.

-- UPDATE --

I've updated create statement to correct one:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
myId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
aNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
anUniqueTextId TEXT NOT NULL,
aText TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(anUniqueTextId, aNumber) REFERENCES otherTable(otherTableId, otherTableValue2) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With respect to your comment you need to specify the `PRIMARY KEY` with a `NULL`value in the QUERY:

```
[db executeUpdate:@"INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
     NULL,
     @(aNumber),
     myData.anUniqueTextId,
     myData.aText];
```

That way the database will fill in the primary key and autoincrement it (SQL Lite specs for `PRIMARY KEY`).

Comment: This is not working with FMDB, it;s crashing somewhere in their classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to change the schema of table.

To auto insert into `myId` field, you must have to add constraint `AUTOINCREMENT` when you create table. Also this field must be use as primary key. So now the schema for table is like:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
myId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
aNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
anUniqueTextId TEXT NOT NULL,
aText TEXT,
FOREIGN KEY(anUniqueTextId, aNumber) REFERENCES otherTable(otherTableId, otherTableValue2) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: I've found some issues with the code. Firstly, there are 2 primary keys, so this `PRIMARY KEY(myId, anUniqueTextId) ON CONFLICT IGNORE,` should be deleted. Rest is of create statement is ok. AUTOINCREMENT is slower "and should be avoided if not strictly needed". "On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually the one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used.
". AUTOINCREMENT just forbids reuse of ROWID.

Comment: You can have multiple primary keys in table. If you use AUTOINCREMENT then you don't need to provide field when you insert records in table.

Comment: If you don't use AUTOINCREMENT you also don't need to provide value during inserting (source: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). I've found the solution, everything is working fine when I only add NULL to INSERT statement. Without AUTOINCREMENT. You can have 1 primary key, but it can be from multiple columns. In your (and my) code there are 2 primary keys: `myId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and `PRIMARY KEY(myId, anUniqueTextId)`. It is invalid.